# Extract Security Settings from Default Domain Policy for bulk windows server using Powershell script

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

Is it possible to extract Security Settings report from Default Domain Policy (i.e. Minimum password age, length, lockout duration, etc.)for bulk windows servers using Powershell scripts?

I am using following script to achieve this objective but getting generated empty output.

[Default Policy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGSFr.png)

```
function GPOreport { 
$computers = Get-Content 'C:\servers.txt'
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'   
ForEach ($computer in $computers) {  

try  
{ 

 Get-GPOReport -Name "Default Domain Policy" -Server $computer -ReportType Html 

} 

catch  

{ 
  Add-content $computer -path "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\Notreachable_Servers.txt"
}  
} 

} 
GPOreport > "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\GPOReport.html"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve by hitting more than one DC as your policies should be replicating across the domain. I think you are throwing an error with Get-GPOReport and that's why you are not seeing any output. Also concatenating your HTML output into a single file is going to make the file invalid HTML which may or may not work in your browser. I would simply check the PDC Emulator (default for the command).

```
Get-GPOReport -Name "Default Domain Policy" -ReportType HTML | Out-File "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\GPOReport.html"
```

If you have to have it for each DC, separate it into individual files.

```
 function GPOreport { 
        #$computers = Get-Content 'C:\servers.txt'
        ForEach ($computer in $computers) {  
        try  
        { 
            Get-GPOReport -Name "Default Domain Policy" -Server $computer -ReportType Html -ErrorAction Stop | Out-File "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\$($computer)GPOReport.html"
        }
        catch
        { 
            Add-content $computer -path "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\Notreachable_Servers.txt"
        }  
    } 
} 

GPOreport
```